# Cannot get flask-talisman to allow Firebase to run

Tags: javascript, firebase, flask

I cannot get the Firebase "Sign in with Google" button to work using flask-talisman. Here is my CSP:

I am not sure if I a missing the right items for 'script-src'. One thing I do know is that if I remove this CSP from my application completely, everything works as normal. So I believe the Firebase issue has to do with what I am putting into the csp.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
csp = {
 'default-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        '\'unsafe-inline\'',
        'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
        'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com',
        'ajax.googleapis.com',
        'cdn.datatables.net',
        'fonts.googleapis.com',
        'gstatic.com',
        'https://js.stripe.com',
    ],
  'script-src': [
      '\'self\'',   
      'unsafe-eval',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'cdn.firebase.com',
      '*.firebaseio.com'
  ],
  'object-src': [
      '\'self\''
  ]
}
talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp)
```

Here is my relevant code in HTML where I use Firebase. It was taken from Google's example.

```
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<button id="sign-out" hidden=true>Sign Out</button>
<div id="login-info" hidden=true>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
```

Then file "script.js" is below:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById('sign-out').onclick = function () {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  };

  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/',
    signInOptions: [
      // Comment out any lines corresponding to providers you did not check in
      // the Firebase console.
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      //firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID

    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    // tosUrl: '/terms-of-service',
    privacyPolicyUrl: '/privacy-policy'
  };

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in, so display the "sign out" button and login info.
      document.getElementById('sign-out').hidden = false;
      document.getElementById('login-info').hidden = false;
      console.log(`Signed in as ${user.displayName} (${user.email})`);
      user.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
        // Add the token to the browser's cookies. The server will then be
        // able to verify the token against the API.
        // SECURITY NOTE: As cookies can easily be modified, only put the
        // token (which is verified server-side) in a cookie; do not add other
        // user information.
        document.cookie = "token=" + token;
      });
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // Show the Firebase login button.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
      // Update the login state indicators.
      document.getElementById('sign-out').hidden = true;
      document.getElementById('login-info').hidden = true;
      // Clear the token cookie.
      document.cookie = "token=";
    }
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('Unable to log in: ' + error)
  });
});
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Look in your browser's console and it should explain the CSP setting that is missing.

Comment: Also your `unsafe-eval` directive needs to be in quotes, same as `'unsafe-inline'`. though adding both `'unsafe-eval'` and `'unsafe-inline'` defeats a lot of the point in using a CSP.